# How does pytorch's nn.Module register submodule?

Tags: python, pytorch

> When I read the source code(python) of torch.nn.Module , I found the
>   attribute `self._modules` has been used in many functions like
>   `self.modules(), self.children()`, etc. However, I didn't find any functions
>   updating it. So, where will the `self._modules` be updated?
>   Furthermore, how does pytorch's `nn.Module` register submodule?

```
class Module(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._backend = thnn_backend
        self._parameters = OrderedDict()
        self._buffers = OrderedDict()
        self._backward_hooks = OrderedDict()
        self._forward_hooks = OrderedDict()
        self._forward_pre_hooks = OrderedDict()
        self._modules = OrderedDict()
        self.training = True

    def named_modules(self, memo=None, prefix=''):
        if memo is None:
            memo = set()
        if self not in memo:
            memo.add(self)
            yield prefix, self
            for name, module in self._modules.items():
                if module is None:
                    continue
                submodule_prefix = prefix + ('.' if prefix else '') + name
                for m in module.named_modules(memo, submodule_prefix):
                    yield m
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modules and parameters are usually registered by setting an attribute for an instance of `nn.module`.
Particularly, this kind of behavior is implemented by customizing the `__setattr__` method:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        def remove_from(*dicts):
            for d in dicts:
                if name in d:
                    del d[name]

        params = self.__dict__.get('_parameters')
        if isinstance(value, Parameter):
            if params is None:
                raise AttributeError(
                    "cannot assign parameters before Module.__init__() call")
            remove_from(self.__dict__, self._buffers, self._modules)
            self.register_parameter(name, value)
        elif params is not None and name in params:
            if value is not None:
                raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' as parameter '{}' "
                                "(torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)"
                                .format(torch.typename(value), name))
            self.register_parameter(name, value)
        else:
            modules = self.__dict__.get('_modules')
            if isinstance(value, Module):
                if modules is None:
                    raise AttributeError(
                        "cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call")
                remove_from(self.__dict__, self._parameters, self._buffers)
                modules[name] = value
            elif modules is not None and name in modules:
                if value is not None:
                    raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' as child module '{}' "
                                    "(torch.nn.Module or None expected)"
                                    .format(torch.typename(value), name))
                modules[name] = value
            else:
                buffers = self.__dict__.get('_buffers')
                if buffers is not None and name in buffers:
                    if value is not None and not isinstance(value, torch.Tensor):
                        raise TypeError("cannot assign '{}' as buffer '{}' "
                                        "(torch.Tensor or None expected)"
                                        .format(torch.typename(value), name))
                    buffers[name] = value
                else:
                    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py to find this method.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how this works with the fact that torch lets you supply your own forward method? If I'm understanding correctly, they are basically just spitting out the layers as they're added to the nn.Module object by checking for new nn.Module objects added as attributes... but you are free to wire those layers together in any which way!

Comment: yes, the module and its children are registered as modules, but other thing is to create a computational graph from them, what is done in forward. Also it is dynamic and is recalc after each fowrard cal.

Answer (score 6):

Add some details to Jiren Jin's answer:

- Layers of a net (inherited from `nn.Module`) are stored in `Module._modules`, which is initialized in `__construct`:

  ```py
  def __init__(self):
      self.__construct()
      # initialize self.training separately from the rest of the internal
      # state, as it is managed differently by nn.Module and ScriptModule
      self.training = True

  def __construct(self):
      """
      Initializes internal Module state, shared by both nn.Module and ScriptModule.
      """
      # ...
      self._modules = OrderedDict()
  ```
- `self._modules` is updated in `__setattr__`. `__setattr__(obj, name, value)` is called when `obj.name = value` is executed. For example, if one defines `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, 1, 1)` when initializing a net inherited from `nn.Module`, the following code from `nn.Module.__setattr__` will be executed:

  ```py
  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
      def remove_from(*dicts):
          for d in dicts:
              if name in d:
                  del d[name]

      params = self.__dict__.get('_parameters')
      if isinstance(value, Parameter):
          # ...
      elif params is not None and name in params:
          # ...
      else:
          modules = self.__dict__.get('_modules') # equivalent to modules = self._modules
          if isinstance(value, Module):
              if modules is None:
                  raise AttributeError(
                      "cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call")
              remove_from(self.__dict__, self._parameters, self._buffers)
              # register the given layer (nn.Conv2d) with its name (conv1)
              # equivalent to self._modules['conv1'] = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, 1, 1)
              modules[name] = value
  ```

Question from comments:

> Do you know how this works with the fact that torch lets you supply your own forward method?

If one runs a forward pass of a net inherited from `nn.Module`, the `nn.Module.__call__` will be called, in which `self.forward` is called. However, one has overrided the `forward` when implementing the net.